# How to showing forefront button on android?

Tags: android

I use `GLSurfaceView`

and I want my `button` displayed in front of `GLSurfaceView`

and my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="my package">

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="back button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this source not showing `Button`. I think behind `GLSurfaceView`

please advice for me

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the `GLSurfaceView` and `Button`'s positions, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="my package">

<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="back button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```